# Meteor Deploy on Webstorm IDE

Tags: javascript, meteor, webstorm

I'm pretty new on **meteor** javascript framework as well as **webstorm** and I already love it.

As I follow the meteor simple-todos tutorial they show how to deploy meteor app to the their hosting by a simple command as below.

```
meteor deploy my_app_name.meteor.com
```

I wonder if it's possible to do the same deployment in webstorm or should I do it on the command line though?

Comment: WebStorm has a terminal tab and the command itself is easy enough. You normally don't need to deploy all that often (if at all, for a toy app). What is easier than that?

Comment: I didnt know it has a terminal tab. Could you please write it as a proper answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the command using the embedded terminal in WebStorm (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), or even create a shell script as a shorthand.

Note that the procedure for deploying to your own production server is different.